# What's the best way to debug RxJava problems with not received messages

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I've an Android app with multiple **observers of type A** that subscribe with several **Observables of type B**. The subscription is done in IO Scheduler and the observation on the Android main thread.

The problem that I've is that **randomlly** after some work one message emitted by B is never received in A and after some hours of debbuging I can't find the cause.

Relevant code **when the problem happens**:

"NEXT1" and "NEXT2" are printed but "RECEIVED","ERROR", COMPLETED aren't.

```
            //The subscription
            B.getMessate()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(A);

            //B
            Observable<msg> getMessage() {
                 return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<msg>() {    
                      public void call(Subscriber<? super msg> subscriber) {
                         ...
                         subscriber.onNext(msg)
                         println("NEXT1")
                      }
                 }).doOnNext({ (o) -> println("NEXT2")});
            }



            //A 
            onNext(msg) {
                  //Never called when problem happens
                  println("RECEIVED")
            }
            onError(msg) {
                  //Never called when problem happens
                  println("ERROR")
            }
            onError(msg) {
                  //Never called when problem happens
                  println("COMPLETED")
            }
```

Anyone has some clue? or any recommendation for debugging that?

What I've checked:

- I've paused the app and checked that all threads to see if one is locked. And aparentlly all working threads are parked and main thread is waiting messages in android message queue.
- Observers never call unsubscribe()

Comment: I'm assuming this is just pseudo code and that you're not directly calling `onNext(msg)` in your `call` method but actually doing `subscribe.onNext(msg)`?

Comment: Why don't you give us a real short piece of code that can reproduce your issue.  It might make it easier to spot the problem.

Comment: I've corrected pseudocode calling onNext on the subscriber.
About giving real short piece of code the problem is that real code that comes before subscriber.onNext() is big and complex. But I think it's irrelevant because "NEXT2" is called. As always the devil is on de details but that code it's my best intent to illustrate my problem in a clear way.

Answer (score 24):

By now I can't reproduce the problem but I've found [RxJavaDebug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaDebug) a very good tool for debugging.

It's use is simple: add the library as a dependency and at application start register a listener:

```
  RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerObservableExecutionHook(new DebugHook(new DebugNotificationListener() {
      public Object onNext(DebugNotification n) {
          Log.v(TAG, "onNext on " + n);
          return super.onNext(n);
      }


        public Object start(DebugNotification n) {
            Log.v(TAG, "start on " + n);
            return super.start(n);
        }


        public void complete(Object context) {
            Log.v(TAG, "complete on " + context);
        }

        public void error(Object context, Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error on " + context);
        }
  }));
```

That will log messages while they go between observables and operators.

Comment: What is `DebugHook`?  Where do you define it.

Comment: `rx.plugins.DebugHook` is an RxJava class, just import it.

Comment: Does it work with RxJava 2.x? I saw this project hasn't been updated for over a year.

Comment: For me context is always `null`. Is this supposed to be like this? Because that way it is really hard to find out which observable completed or threw an error.

Comment: Found the solution to the `null` problem: Using `rx.plugins.SimpleDebugNotificationListener` takes care of filling the context. :)

Comment: @ubuntudroid Do you have to implement any methods for SimpleDebugNotificationListener?

Comment: @ZinanXing you can use RxJava2Debug for RxJava 2.x. It follows the same principles, just packaged and offered in a nicer way :)