# RxJava groupBy and subsequent blocking operations (onComplete missing?)

Tags: java, rx-java

I have boiled my problem down into the following snippet:

```
Observable<Integer> numbers = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);

Observable<GroupedObservable<Integer,Integer>> outer = numbers.groupBy(i->i%3);
System.out.println(outer.count().toBlocking().single());
```

which blocks interminably. I've been [reading](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/844) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442032/rxjava-debug-chain-that-seems-to-block-forever) [posts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2320) and believe I understand the problem: GroupedObservables will not call onComplete until their inner Observables have also been completed. Unfortunately though I still can't get the above snippet to print!

For example, the following:

```
Observable<Integer> just = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);

Observable<GroupedObservable<Integer,Integer>> groupBy = just.groupBy(i->i%3);
groupBy.subscribe(inner -> inner.ignoreElements());
System.out.println(groupBy.count().toBlocking().single());
```

still does nothing. Have I misunderstood the problem? Is there another problem? In short, how can I get the above snippets to work?

Many thanks in advance,
Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to consume the groups in some fashion. Your second example doesn't work because you have two independent subscription to the grouping operation.

Usually, the solution is `flatMap`, but not not with `ignoreElements` because that will just complete and `count` won't get any elements. Instead, you can use `takeLast(1)`:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
    .groupBy(k -> k % 3)
    .flatMap(g -> g.takeLast(1))
    .count()
    .toBlocking()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm still having problems unfortunately when applying this to my case. What if I want to count the elements of the 3 groups? Essentially I want something like: 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1.

Comment: or rather, 0:1, 1:1, 2:1!